# What is the best way to get 51, out of the following string

Tags: ruby, regex, url

What is the best way to get '51', out of the following string in ruby :

```
"<https://api.example.com/users/lgs/api?page=2>; rel=\"next\", <https://api.example.com/users/lgs/api?page=51>; rel=\"last\""
```

Thanks in advance
Luca

Comment: Do you know how the string was encoded? Can you give some more examples, including some more edge cases? How much control do you have over the input? What parts can you guarantee will always be the same, and what parts can change?

Comment: (why) did you tag it with your answer?

Comment: @sehe ... ok, now I get it ( http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know there're only two numbers in that string then this is enough:

```
str = '"<https://api.example.com/users/lgs/api?page=2>; rel=\"next\", <https://api.example.com/users/lgs/api?page=51>; rel=\"last\""'
p str.scan(/\d+/).last #=> "51"
```

If not then provide more detail to make the regex more precise. Also you can add `to_i` if you need the answer as a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp in this way:

> res = str.match /.*page=(\d+).*/

in this way you are "capturing all the digits between "(" and ")" (in the last token), and you result will be store in

> res.captures.first 
>   (or simply in $1 variable)